# How do i definitively align dynamically sized content with CSS not fixed width?

Tags: html, css

I use to be a full stack web developer 15 years ago when CSS was budding.  We of course used tables for everything. Well i'm back and really put some time into CSS because i have to say its cool.. But i find it AN ABSOLUTE RIDICULOUS PAIN to do some simple things that tables STILL do far easier and better than Divs with CSS.   I've found dozens of alignment solutions online (Most that don't work or only work if you have fixed pixel size content, but only a couple few that just look nasty bulky and require additional header/trailer container html parent elements to properly center a simple element like a button or image.  It just seems like the resulting CSS is far more of a work around than what people claim Tables were.  So my question is what is the simplest repeatable approach for dynamically aligning content with CSS (Aligning Right, Left, Center...Both vertical and horizontal.)?

Comment: text-align: Center;

Comment: Your question is verging on asking for an opinion, that being said I just say that if you want some good plain old info checkout https://css-tricks.com

Comment: Well i looked at this and strangely enough the article that talks about aligning stuff still shows the good old "Table" as being the simplest solution to the alignment issues.   I think anyone that has sat down seriously to do dynamic alignment with CSS but used tables before would be thinking "WTF is this" in regards to CSS... Here is the article btw:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/absolute-center-vertical-horizontal-an-image/

Comment: That's one of those things that's not broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will keep this answer short and simple.

**The Best Way**

Use `grid`. It's the most robust css stuff out there. With tons of customization, you can make the page look nearly exactly the way you want. It's a 2-dimensional system. Well, the configuration can sometimes takes a bit pain. If the layout is pretty simple and speed is of essence, try `flex`

The best resource: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

**The Easy Way**

Use `flex`. It's an efficient, simple way to go for if your layout isn't too demanding. Relatively easy to setup. It's 1-dimensional system, however. If you're looking for complex grid, you're barking the wrong tree. Try `grid`.

The best resource: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

These are the ones that I always use. I have also outlined a simple tip when you would want to go for one over other. It's worth mastering both. Trust me. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this is respectable answer to address the issues.  I glossed over both of these Grid/Flex to avoid un-necessary complexity but it seems i may need to take them on.  I just don't understand why all of these things are even needed when the table does most all of this precisely and in a far more simplistic way especially if you understand how to nest them in order to achieve precise layout.

Comment: @TimWiley Here's a good article that sums it up nicely: https://medium.com/@js_tut/new-things-css-grid-brings-to-the-table-e465cb5d2841

Comment: Wow what a fantastic and sarcastic article medium wrote... Amazing writing... The more i ramp up on this front end stuff the more i see medium seems to really have the most rounded articles from senior people that don't jump on the trend bandwagons... you can tell the writers have been around the block rather than blowing their horns for the latest craze.  Thanks for this article.